# How to extract node from object based on object prop?

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone i have an object

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    uniqueId: 'u_a',
  },
  groupA: {
    uniqueId: 'u_groupA', 
    nested: {
      b: {
        uniqueId: 'u_b',
      },
      c: {
        uniqueId: 'u_c',
      },
      anotherGroup: {
        uniqueId: 'u_anotherGroup',
        nested: {
          d: {
            uniqueId: 'u_d',
          },
          e: {
            uniqueId: 'u_e',
          },
        }
      },
    }
  },
};
```

and i have an **array that holds the uniqueId values ** like this

`[ 'u_a', 'u_b', 'u_c' ]` and so on so

1. **What i want to do is loop through the array and extract the specific nodes -- for more understanding**
2. if the array is [ 'u_a' ]
   The result will be

```js
const result = {
   a: {
    uniqueId: 'u_a',
  },
};
```

1. **And If The Array is [ 'u_b' ]**
   the result will be

```js
const result = {
  groupA: {
    uniqueId: 'u_groupA', 
    nested: {
      b: {
        uniqueId: 'u_b',
      },
    }
  }
};
```

- **And If The array is [ 'u_a', 'u_b', 'u_d' ]**
  The result will be:

```js
const result = {
  a: {
    uniqueId: 'u_a',
  },
  groupA: {
    uniqueId: 'u_groupA', 
    nested: {
      b: {
        uniqueId: 'u_b',
      },
      anotherGroup: {
        uniqueId: 'u_anotherGroup',
        nested: {
          d: {
            uniqueId: 'u_d',
          },
        }
      },
    }
  },
};
```

and So on

**How can i do that**

1. List of uniqueIDs
2. Loop through them and search for each one inside the object
3. extract the founded node only ***Not All Elements***

`Thanks in Advance.`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`filterDeep`](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep) from [`deepdash`](https://deepdash.io/)

```js
deepdash(_);

const obj = {a:{uniqueId:"u_a"},groupA:{uniqueId:"u_groupA",nested:{b:{uniqueId:"u_b"},c:{uniqueId:"u_c"},anotherGroup:{uniqueId:"u_anotherGroup",nested:{d:{uniqueId:"u_d"},e:{uniqueId:"u_e"}}}}}}

const filter = ['u_a', 'u_b', 'u_d']

const result = _.filterDeep(obj, val => _.includes(filter, val))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/deepdash/browser/deepdash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think this is what i want except `In the expected answer i can't find uniqueId in ---> groupA and anotherGroup`

Comment: Also i what i want is to search on `values not keys`  and the result should be like the last example in the post After edit, can i do that ?

Comment: Thanks this is very good but the the top level node `groupA + anotherGroup` always missing other props like their own `uniqueId`  or any other prop.
the result should be like my last example if it's possible