# How can I search and get a node based on prop value?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hello everyone I want to extract a node based on prop value in object and here is what I want

**Notes:**

1. **uniqueId** ---> is the key that I want.
2. **items** ---> is Fixed Key For All nested objects
3. ['item1', ...etc] ----> array of prop to search of inside the object as explained below

**My Object is:**

```js
const obj = {
  home: {
    label: 'home',
    alt: 'home',
    uniqueId: 'home', 
  },
  tasks: {
    label: 'tasks',
    alt: 'tasks',
    uniqueId: 'tasks',
  },
  cms: {
    label: 'cms',
    alt: 'cms',
    uniqueId: 'cms',
    items: {
      news: {
        label:'news',
        alt: 'cms-news',
        uniqueId: 'news',
      },
      announcements: {
        label: 'cmsAnnouncementsLabel',
        alt: 'cms-announcements',
        uniqueId: 'announcements',
      },
    }
  },
  supervision: {
    label: 'supervision',
    alt: 'supervision',
    uniqueId: 'supervision',
    items: {
      violations: {
        label: 'violationsManegment',
        alt: 'supervisors',
        uniqueId: 'violations',
        items: {
          violationTemplates: {
            label: 'violationTemplates',
            alt: 'violations',
            uniqueId: 'violationTemplates',
          },
          paradigms: {
            label: 'paradimsManegment',
            alt: 'paradims',
            uniqueId: 'paradigms',
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Results:**

1. Case 1: if I want to search for **['home']** the result will be

```js
const result = {
  home: {
    label: 'home',
    alt: 'home',
    uniqueId: 'home', 
  }
}
```

2. Case 2 if want to search for **['announcements']** which is a nested object the result should be

```js
const result = {
  cms: {
    label: 'cms',
    alt: 'cms',
    uniqueId: 'cms',
    items: {
      announcements: {
        label: 'cmsAnnouncementsLabel',
        alt: 'cms-announcements',
        uniqueId: 'announcements',
      },
    }
  },
}
```

**Note that the** ***News is Ignored because it's not in the search array***

3. case 3 if I want to search of **['paradigms']** the result will be

```js
const result = {
  supervision: {
    label: 'supervision',
    alt: 'supervision',
    uniqueId: 'supervision',
    items: {
      violations: {
        label: 'violationsManegment',
        alt: 'supervisors',
        uniqueId: 'violations',
        items: {
          paradigms: {
            label: 'paradimsManegment',
            alt: 'paradims',
            uniqueId: 'paradigms',
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Violation Template ignored**

4.Last case if I want to search For **['violationTemplates', 'home', 'paradigms']**

```js
const result = {
  home: {
    label: 'home',
    alt: 'home',
    uniqueId: 'home', 
  },
  tasks: {
    label: 'tasks',
    alt: 'tasks',
    uniqueId: 'tasks',
  },
  supervision: {
    label: 'supervision',
    alt: 'supervision',
    uniqueId: 'supervision',
    items: {
      violations: {
        label: 'violationsManegment',
        alt: 'supervisors',
        uniqueId: 'violations',
        items: {
          violationTemplates: {
            label: 'violationTemplates',
            alt: 'violations',
            uniqueId: 'violationTemplates',
          },
          paradigms: {
            label: 'paradimsManegment',
            alt: 'paradims',
            uniqueId: 'paradigms',
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I used deepDash ** ----> findDeep and filterDeep as in here [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517446/how-to-extract-node-from-object-based-on-object-prop) but they are ignoring parents nodes props

How can I do that?

Comment: What about the native array->filter ?

Comment: @mpm could u please provide an example because i don't understand what you mean.
but keep in mind the array is the source to loop through then you search for each item inside the object then gather the results to be like the main object

Comment: Ah ok sorry, misunderstood your question

Comment: I've got a question on case 4: since you did not add "tasks" to the search keys, why does it show up in the resulting object?

Comment: @JacopoTedeschi because this structure is a sideMenu Structure, so if the user choosed a nested item i must get it's parents to show dropdown menus ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One possible implementation

I would dare say this problem may be more complex than it looks at start. I tried to create an implementation of the specs you gave us using Lodash, and forking [Rambda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/) mergeDeepLeft porting it to the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) `_.has` and `_.isObject` functions. The resulting code is not optimized, and it's pretty long, but I hope it may offer you a starting point over which you can optimize if you need an more performant algorithm.

### Can I quickly try the function in the browser?

Of course! I actually made a Codepen where you can try the algorithm, just remember to open your browser console to see the test results! Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/jhack_jos/pen/ZEBYPbR

### How to use it

```
//the function signature
result = findDeep(object, query, options);
```

Where:

- **object** is the object were to look inside
- **query** can be either:

  - a string, in which case will treated as the key to search
  - an array, in which case each of the elements will be treated as a key to search
- **options** is an optional object that may contain one or both of the following keys:

  `{merge: "yes", keeptree: "yes"}`

  - `merge: "yes"` tells findDeep to do a mergeDeepLeft on the resulting array, such that: a) without it you get back an array with the search results for each of the keys you searched for b) you get one merged object.
  - `keeptree: "yes"` tells findDeep to return the whole tree, and not just the object that was attached to the key or keys that we were looking for.
- for your usage case you should always call findDeep with both options. Such as like this:

  `result = findDeep(obj, ["key1", "key2"], {merge: "yes", keeptree: "yes"}`
- **result** can be one of the following:

  - the object the searched key pointed to (one key, no options)
  - an array with a list of objects the searched keys pointed to (multiple keys, no options)
  - an object containing all the merged results from all keys (multiple keys, `options = {merge: yes"}`
  - by specifying `options = {keeptree: "yes"}` you will also get the keys in the hierarchy of the searched key.

### Practical examples of usage

I can see my explanation could be quite contrived, that's why I prepared a series of examples that hopefully should clarify how the function is used. First I introduce you to the test dataset, which is the one you give us in your question:

**test dataset**

```
/* Test dataset */
const dataset = {
  home: {
    label: 'home',
    alt: 'home',
    uniqueId: 'home', 
  },
  tasks: {
    label: 'tasks',
    alt: 'tasks',
    uniqueId: 'tasks',
  },
  cms: {
    label: 'cms',
    alt: 'cms',
    uniqueId: 'cms',
    items: {
      news: {
        label:'news',
        alt: 'cms-news',
        uniqueId: 'news',
      },
      announcements: {
        label: 'cmsAnnouncementsLabel',
        alt: 'cms-announcements',
        uniqueId: 'announcements',
      },
    }
  },
  supervision: {
    label: 'supervision',
    alt: 'supervision',
    uniqueId: 'supervision',
    items: {
      violations: {
        label: 'violationsManegment',
        alt: 'supervisors',
        uniqueId: 'violations',
        items: {
          violationTemplates: {
            label: 'violationTemplates',
            alt: 'violations',
            uniqueId: 'violationTemplates',
          },
          paradigms: {
            label: 'paradimsManegment',
            alt: 'paradims',
            uniqueId: 'paradigms',
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**examples**

**CASE 1**

```
//CASE 1
result = findDeep(dataset, "home", {keeptree: "yes"});
result = {
            "label": "tasks",
            "alt": "tasks",
            "uniqueId": "tasks",
            "items": {
                "violations": {
                    "label": "violationsManegment",
                    "alt": "supervisors",
                    "uniqueId": "violations",
                    "items": {
                        "violationTemplates": {
                            "label": "violationTemplates",
                            "alt": "violations",
                            "uniqueId": "violationTemplates"
                        },
                        "paradigms": {
                            "label": "paradimsManegment",
                            "alt": "paradims",
                            "uniqueId": "paradigms"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "announcements": {
                    "label": "cmsAnnouncementsLabel",
                    "alt": "cms-announcements",
                    "uniqueId": "announcements"
                }
            }
        }
```

**CASE 2**

```
//CASE 2
result = findDeep(dataset, "announcements", {keeptree: "yes"});
result = {
    "cms": {
        "label": "cms",
        "alt": "cms",
        "uniqueId": "cms",
        "items": {
            "announcements": {
                "label": "cmsAnnouncementsLabel",
                "alt": "cms-announcements",
                "uniqueId": "announcements"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CASE 3**

```
//CASE 3
result = findDeep(dataset, "paradigms", {keeptree: "yes"});
result = {
    "supervision": {
        "label": "supervision",
        "alt": "supervision",
        "uniqueId": "supervision",
        "items": {
            "violations": {
                "label": "violationsManegment",
                "alt": "supervisors",
                "uniqueId": "violations",
                "items": {
                    "paradigms": {
                        "label": "paradimsManegment",
                        "alt": "paradims",
                        "uniqueId": "paradigms"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CASE 4**

```
//CASE 4
result = findDeep(dataset, ['violationTemplates', 'home', 'paradigms'], {merge: "yes", keeptree: "yes"});
result = {
    "supervision": {
        "label": "supervision",
        "alt": "supervision",
        "uniqueId": "supervision",
        "items": {
            "violations": {
                "label": "violationsManegment",
                "alt": "supervisors",
                "uniqueId": "violations",
                "items": {
                    "paradigms": {
                        "label": "paradimsManegment",
                        "alt": "paradims",
                        "uniqueId": "paradigms"
                    },
                    "violationTemplates": {
                        "label": "violationTemplates",
                        "alt": "violations",
                        "uniqueId": "violationTemplates"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "home": {
        "label": "home",
        "alt": "home",
        "uniqueId": "home"
    }
}
```

**CASE 4b**

```
//CASE 4b
result = findDeep(dataset, ['home', 'paradigms'], {merge: "yes", keeptree: "yes"});
result = {
    "supervision": {
        "label": "supervision",
        "alt": "supervision",
        "uniqueId": "supervision",
        "items": {
            "violations": {
                "label": "violationsManegment",
                "alt": "supervisors",
                "uniqueId": "violations",
                "items": {
                    "paradigms": {
                        "label": "paradimsManegment",
                        "alt": "paradims",
                        "uniqueId": "paradigms"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "home": {
        "label": "home",
        "alt": "home",
        "uniqueId": "home"
    }
}
```

BELOW THE EXTRAS: things the function does that were not required.

**EXTRA 1**

```
//EXTRA 1
result = findDeep(dataset, "violationTemplates");
result = {
    "label": "supervision",
    "alt": "supervision",
    "uniqueId": "supervision",
    "items": {
        "violations": {
            "label": "violationsManegment",
            "alt": "supervisors",
            "uniqueId": "violations",
            "items": {
                "violationTemplates": {
                    "label": "violationTemplates",
                    "alt": "violations",
                    "uniqueId": "violationTemplates"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EXTRA 2**

```
//EXTRA 2
result = findDeep(dataset, ["supervision", "violationTemplates", "announcements", "tasks"]);
result = [
    {
        "label": "supervision",
        "alt": "supervision",
        "uniqueId": "supervision",
        "items": {
            "violations": {
                "label": "violationsManegment",
                "alt": "supervisors",
                "uniqueId": "violations",
                "items": {
                    "violationTemplates": {
                        "label": "violationTemplates",
                        "alt": "violations",
                        "uniqueId": "violationTemplates"
                    },
                    "paradigms": {
                        "label": "paradimsManegment",
                        "alt": "paradims",
                        "uniqueId": "paradigms"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "supervision",
        "alt": "supervision",
        "uniqueId": "supervision",
        "items": {
            "violations": {
                "label": "violationsManegment",
                "alt": "supervisors",
                "uniqueId": "violations",
                "items": {
                    "violationTemplates": {
                        "label": "violationTemplates",
                        "alt": "violations",
                        "uniqueId": "violationTemplates"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "cms",
        "alt": "cms",
        "uniqueId": "cms",
        "items": {
            "announcements": {
                "label": "cmsAnnouncementsLabel",
                "alt": "cms-announcements",
                "uniqueId": "announcements"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "tasks",
        "alt": "tasks",
        "uniqueId": "tasks"
    }
]
```

**EXTRA 3**

```
//EXTRA 3
result = findDeep(dataset, ["supervision", "violationTemplates", "announcements", "tasks"], {merge: "yes"});
result = {
    "label": "tasks",
    "alt": "tasks",
    "uniqueId": "tasks",
    "items": {
        "violations": {
            "label": "violationsManegment",
            "alt": "supervisors",
            "uniqueId": "violations",
            "items": {
                "violationTemplates": {
                    "label": "violationTemplates",
                    "alt": "violations",
                    "uniqueId": "violationTemplates"
                },
                "paradigms": {
                    "label": "paradimsManegment",
                    "alt": "paradims",
                    "uniqueId": "paradigms"
                }
            }
        },
        "announcements": {
            "label": "cmsAnnouncementsLabel",
            "alt": "cms-announcements",
            "uniqueId": "announcements"
        }
    }
}
```

### The source code

```
const findDeep = ( () => {
  /* Libraries */

  /* This code was forked from Rambda by Jacopo Tedeschi. Dependencies were adjusted so that it depends on Lodash instead.
     It wouldn't be hard to even make it completely library independent  */
  const mergeWithKey = function mergeWithKey(fn, l, r) {
    var result = {};
    var k;

    for (k in l) {
      if (_.has(l, k)) {
        if(_.has(r, k))
        {
            result[k] = fn(k, l[k], r[k]);
        } else {
            result[k] = l[k];
        }
      }
    }

    for (k in r) {
      if (_.has(r, k) && !(_.has(result, k))) {
        result[k] = r[k];
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  const mergeDeepWithKey = function mergeDeepWithKey(fn, lObj, rObj) {
    return mergeWithKey(function(k, lVal, rVal) {
      if (_.isObject(lVal) && _.isObject(rVal)) {
        return mergeDeepWithKey(fn, lVal, rVal);
      } else {
        return fn(k, lVal, rVal);
      }
    }, lObj, rObj);
  };

  const mergeDeepLeft = function mergeDeepLeft(lObj, rObj) {
    return mergeDeepWithKey(function(k, lVal, rVal) {
      return lVal;
    }, lObj, rObj);
  };
  
  /* Code below here was written by Jacopo Tedeschi */
  
  function _deleteSibilings(object, searchKey) {
    return _.has(object, searchKey)
           ? {[searchKey] : object[searchKey]}
           : _.reduce(object, (acc, value, key) => {
                      acc[key] = _.isObject(value)
                                 ? _deleteSibilings(value, searchKey)
                                 : value;
                      return acc;
              }, {});
   };
  
  function _findDeepHelper(collection, key, options)
  {  
    if(_.has(collection, key))
    {
      //here we make sure we also return the key
      return _.get(options, "keeptree") == "yes"
              ? key
              : collection[key];
    } else 
    {
      const resultKey = _.findKey(collection, 
                                  value =>  _.isObjectLike(value)
                                            && _findDeepHelper(value, key, options));
      
      return _.get(options, "keeptree") == "yes"
             ? resultKey
             : _.get(collection, resultKey);
    }
  }
  
  function _findDeep(collection, key, options)
  {
    let result = _findDeepHelper(collection, key, options);
    
    if(_.get(options, "keeptree") == "yes")
    {
      result = _.pick(collection, result);
    }
    
    return _deleteSibilings(result, key);
  }
  
  function _findMultipleDeep(collection, keys, options)
  {
    return _.isArray(keys)
           ? _.map(keys, key => _findDeep(collection, key, options)) 
           : _findDeep(collection, keys, options);
  }
  
  function _mergeQueries(queries)
  {
    if(_.isArray(queries))
    {
      return queries.length > 1
             ? _.reduce(queries, mergeDeepLeft)
             : _.get(queries, 0);
    } else
    {
      return queries;
    }
  }
  
  return (collection, keys, options) =>
  {
      const result = _findMultipleDeep(collection, keys, options);
      return  _.get(options, "merge") == "yes"
              ? _mergeQueries(result)
              : result;
  };
})();
```

### The algorithm explained

**Searching only 1 key**

That's the order in which I go about in the algorithm to create the `result` object you need:

1. Look inside the IIE (Immediately Invoked Expression) I use to delimit my scope and avoid global scope pollution.
2. The first thing you should look at is the `_findDeep` function. The first part of the algorithm is handled there.
3. it calls `_findDeepHelper`, which does the following:

   1. searches were the key is located in the object with a recursive algorithm
   2. after the key is found, it traverses back the tree.
   3. while going up, it returns the key name of the current node
   4. as a result, we get back the key of the uppermost node in the root of the object that contains the key that we are looking for
4. then, using Lodash `_.pick`, it creates a new object selecting only the root key that contains the key we are looking for
5. finally, using `_deleteSibilings` it deletes all siblings of the key that we are looking for
6. we now have the resulting object!

**Searching multiple keys**

So, how to you get to search multiple keys?

1. to simplify, I forked `mergeDeepLeft` from the Rambda library and changed a few functions so that it depends on Lodash instead
2. I do each search separately, then use `mergeDeepLeft` to merge the queries together
3. if there are colliding keys, the data resulting for keys in the left part of the search key array will be lost, only keys resulting from the keys on the right will be kept

**Why is there also functionality I did not request?**

Since I were at it, I spent just a little extra time and made the resulting algorithm, which I called findDeep, a bit more flexible and convenient to use in different use cases. This generated just a little bit of extra code, but I hope it could serve you even better that way.

### Thank you for reading!

I'd be glad to give any further explanation, may you need it.
As a bonus I would add it could be possible to write some clever utility function as a lowdb/lodash mixin in order to enable us to have a shorter syntax and still properly chain. That is, however, probably more than what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, regardless the length of the implementation, but it could be enhanced even more.